# Are there functions which take themselves as input?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, recursion

Are there functions which takes itself as an argument? Like: $f(x,f(x_{n\pm1}))$

A functions which value at a given point depends on its value on the next,or previous intake value. Or:  $f(x,f(x))$.

A function which value at a given point depends on itself at that given point. This seems like nonsense because it should be: $f(x,f(x,f(x,f(x....))$

Comment: In an expression like $f(x,f(x))$, the outer $f$ has two arguments while the inner $f$ has only one argument, which means you must be referring to two different functions by the same letter $f$. Also, there is technically a difference between taking a function as an input (like a derivative operator does with functions, and returns functions as outputs), and taking the result of applying a function to something else as an input, (like the composition $f(g(x))$ takes the result of applying $g$ to $x$ and applies $f$ to that... or you can view composition as a binary operation of two functions),

Comment: @runway44 "which means you must be referring to two different functions" Unless it's [variadic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function).

Comment: Sure. One can uniquely define the factorial as 
$$\operatorname{fact}(n)=\begin{cases} 1&n=0\\ n\operatorname{fact}(n-1)&n\neq 0\end{cases}$$

Comment: What you propose in the last line seems to be a generalization of superfunctions, if you clearly define $x$ and $x_n$ in a proper way. This might interest you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfunction

Comment: Vaguely relevant: [the set-theoretic motivation for Laver tables](https://www.lmno.cnrs.fr/archives/dehornoy/Talks/Dyz.pdf).